# Good way to store Asset tracking data in CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am building a simple asset tracking application on Azure that need to capture details around

1. asset information,
2. its current location
3. Time series data with asset Id and its location. to track the asset over time. ***possibly for years***.

The asset in question is going to stream its location details at a regular interval of time say every 10 sec on a `Event Grid` I want to stream this data in to a archival for any future analysis, and at the same time also query for other assets in a `geospatial`distance of `1 km` and send them a notification.

So I am looking to understand what is the best way to store this information in a `CosmosDB` is it efficient to store this in one collection for asset like this partitioned by asset Id

```
Asset : {
  AssetId : "123456",
  RegisteredAddress : "123, abc xyz",
  ZipCode : "12345"
  MobileNo: "32423432432"
  CurrentLocation: Point {12, 123}
  LocationHistory:[
       {Timestamp: 1/1/2019 12:20:10, Location: Point{12, 123}},
       {Timestamp: 1/1/2019 12:20:20, Location: Point{12, 123}},
       {Timestamp: 1/1/2019 12:20:30, Location: Point{12, 123}},
       {Timestamp: 1/1/2019 12:20:40, Location: Point{12, 123}},
       {Timestamp: 1/1/2019 12:20:50, Location: Point{12, 123}},
]
}
```

or would be better to maintain a separate collection for  managing `LocationHistory`.

```
LocationHistory: {
 AssetId: 12345, 
 Timestamp: "1/1/2019 12:20:10", 
 Location: Point{12, 123}
}
```

BTW I am new to `Document store` so please feel free to suggest an better option if possible.

I am really looking to minimize my operational cost here so how does the above 2 approach impact on my overall operational cost. Assuming I use a Azure Function to be triggred on a Event Grid event and update this collection.

**Update 1:**

based on ***Joel Oughton***'s answer below, I have tried to move both the metadata about the asset as well as the tracking details as separate documents but on a single collection. For this I have made the following changes:

1. I have added additional 2 attributes to all the class namely `_PartitionKey` and `_Service`
2. I am building and updating the `_PartitionKey` before storing the event.

I am now using the following code to capture the asset metadata:

```
assetInfo.LastUpdated = DateTimeOffset.Now;
assetInfo._PartitionKey = $"assets_{assetInfo.Address.State.ToLower()}_{assetInfo.Address.City.ToLower()}";
assetInfo._Service = "assets";

Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(config.DatabaseName, config.CollectionName);
var documnent = await DBUtility.GetDocumentClient().UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionUri, assetInfo);
```

in the same way to store the tracking information I am using this code below:

```
tracking.UnixTimestamp = DBUtility.GetEpochTimeMillis(DateTime.UtcNow);
tracking.Id = $"{tracking.AssetId.ToLower()}_{tracking.UnixTimestamp}";
tracking.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
tracking._PartitionKey = $"tracking_{tracking.AssetId.ToLower()}_{DateTime.Today.ToString("D")}";
tracking._Service = "trackings";

Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(config.DatabaseName, config.CollectionName);
var documnent = await DBUtility.GetDocumentClient().UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionUri, tracking);
requestCharge += documnent.RequestCharge;
```

this seams to be working well, however I am having a tough time deciding on how to query for all the assets that are say `1 Km` away from the given coordinates. Issue is i need to pick the latest tracking event from each asset before using the `ST_DISTANCE`.

Can someone please suggest how I can create a query that is able to find all the assets details whose latest coordinate are `1 Km` away from a given `Point` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB has document size limits and performance can deteriorate with larger documents.

I would store a metadata type document that includes the asset id, address etc and a document that includes the asset id, timestamp and location.

Additionally the current location could be determined using the latest time stamped location instead of having to update the metadata record on each change.

This structure would allow for efficient read and write operations and prevent document size limitations from being an issue.

If you want to optimise your operational cost and are using .NET you could use https://github.com/cloud-maker-ai/Nebula (disclaimer: I'm the author). Otherwise ensure that RU throughout is shared over your multiple collections or both document types are stored in the same collection with logical separation.

Comment: Thanks! I did take a look at the `Nebula`,  very interesting but as most of my code will be in Azure Functions I am just picking some concepts from here. BTW I have updated my post with additional details based on your suggestion. Would you be able to help with the query for locating the nearby assets. Also would appreciate if you can suggest if the changes are in the right direction.